# How do I create a variable that can be modified in any file in the folder for cgi python?

Tags: php, python, html, cgi

I'm coming from php so I know that

```
$_SESSION['variable'] = 55
```

Can be modified from between pages and is not depending on an external file being imported to do.

***How do I do this with python? I am using .cgi scripts.***

Googling around brings me to this idea of using a file which stores values  across files but the changes only to the original file will be felt globally any other changes are local.

For example, the suggestion is:

**config.py**

```
variable = 5
```

**otherfile.py**

```
import config

print config.variable
config.variable = 3
```

I don't think this will give me the result that I want. I don't think the changes in otherfile will pass to a different file I made.

Comment: This question is unanswerable without knowing what web framework you are using.

Comment: I'm not using any. I am just writing with python .cgi. I run my code in apache 2. Do I need a framework? I was thinking flask or django might have some function that does this.

Comment: Yes, even without this question; you shouldn't use CGI anyway. If you want to do anything non trivial then definitely. All frameworks will have some kind of session functionality.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be looking into one.

Comment: Can I still use my preexisting CGI files with other frameworks like flask or django or will I have to change the filenames and paths?